# Typescript / Angular 8: Change individual button color displayed using ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am displaying a text (word by word) with an ngFor directive. Inside the ngFor I have an if-else-statement with a condition that determines whether a word gets displayed as a `<span>` or as a `<button>` - this works already.

Concerning the buttons, I want to behave them the following way: **On the first click on a single button only this button should change the background color to red, when clicked again the background color should change back to grey as before.**

The code I wrote so far changes the button background color of ALL buttons instead of only the single button clicked on.
How can I change that only a single button changes its color?

HTML:

```
<div id="learnerText" *ngFor="let item of wordsJsonText; let i = index" [ngClass]="{active: i === activeIndex}">
  <div class="container" id="textBody" id="learnerText">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.is_title==='false' && item.has_context==='false'; then caseA else caseB">
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #caseA id="textBody" id="learnerText">
      <span id="learnerText">{{item.form}}</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #caseB>        
        <div *ngIf="item.is_title==='false' && item.has_context==='true'">
          <Button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : toggle ? 'red' : 'grey'}"
          id="bodyButton" text=item.form (click)="onClickMe(item.lemma, item.pos); toggleColor()">{{item.form}}</Button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
private toggle: boolean;

toggleColor() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
}
```

Comment: All the `background-color`s are bound to the same variable `toggle` that's why they all change. Let me look for an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my opinion to do this would be to simply add an extra field to your wordsJsonText array under each object - say `toggled: boolean`.

```
[{form: 'abc', toggled: false}, {form: 'def', toggled: false}]
```

Then you can do the following on your button.

```
(click)="item.toggled = !item.toggled"
```

You can then use this `item.toggled` value to assign the class to the button.

Comment: as I didn't want to alter the json I tried the approach of adding a boolean value in my typescript code like the answer below suggests. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following

```
export interface JsonWordWrapper {
    jsonWord: JsonWord;
    checked: boolean;
}

toggleColor(item: JsonWrapper) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
}
```

And at the place where you assign your `wordsJsonText` variable, instead of

```
this.wordsJsonText = wordsJson
```

use

```
this.wordsJsonText = wordsJson.map<JsonWrapper>(w => {
    jsonWord: w,
    checked: false
});
```

And your html would be

```
<button [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : item.checked ? 'red' : 'grey'}" (click)="toggleColor(item)" ...>{{ item.jsonWord.form }}</button>
```

This way you have a generic approach without changing your initial data structure in json

Comment: I found a solution to my problem using your idea. I added the boolean variable "checked" when reading in my wordsJsonText - without creating an extra interface.
Then I changed the html as you suggested and returned the item with the function "toggleColor", which is read by the same typescript function, just like you posted. Now the button color change works perfectly. Thank you!